# Hide a tab if there is no Option checked

Tags: php, html

i work in a new Company and they have a complicated cms and i dont know what to do.

The issue:

There are Products, they have a Option and some have no Options. This Code under this is in the first page of the shopping card:

```
<div class="warenkorb_tarifoptionen" id="warenkorb_zusatz_label">Choose Option: </div>

<?php

    foreach($warenkorb_tarif['tarifoptionen'] as $option_id => $tarifoption)    {
        echo '
        <div class="warenkorb_tarifoptionen_name">'.$tarifoption['optionsname'].':</div>
        <div class="warenkorb_selectbox" id="warenkorb_aktion_verfugbar">'.$tarifoption['optionsanzeige'].'</div>
        <div class="warenkorb_optionsinfo">'.$tarifoption['optionsmouseover'].'</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        ';
    }

}
?>
```

Some Products have Options. Then it makes sense to choose a Option. But the Text: **Choose Option**: is also shown by products without a option.

The Question: can i disable this text by products without a Option? Because the text is always online - even there is nothing to select.

Thank you guys, its my first time here in this platform. I hope you unstand my issue.

Comment: You could just put an `if (!empty($warenkorb_tarif['tarifoptionen']))` around the first `div`, if by "disable this text" you mean remove it. Or, if you want it disabled, make it grey if this condition is true.

Comment: Hey Karsten, with "disable" i mean to remove the text.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole block in a check to see if any options exist, before outputting anything.

```
<?php if (!empty($warenkorb_tarif['tarifoptionen'])): ?>
    <div class="warenkorb_tarifoptionen" id="warenkorb_zusatz_label">Choose Option: </div>

    <?php

    foreach($warenkorb_tarif['tarifoptionen'] as $option_id => $tarifoption)    {
        echo '
        <div class="warenkorb_tarifoptionen_name">'.$tarifoption['optionsname'].':</div>
        <div class="warenkorb_selectbox" id="warenkorb_aktion_verfugbar">'.$tarifoption['optionsanzeige'].'</div>
        <div class="warenkorb_optionsinfo">'.$tarifoption['optionsmouseover'].'</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        ';
    }

    }
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you EriK. If i use your code, all the text disapears - even the other text and images in the shopping card

Answer (score 0):

@Karsten Koop - you was right!

```
if (!empty($warenkorb_tarif['tarifoptionen']))
```

made it!